# configure selinux to allow sudoers on nfs share

Tags: centos, selinux

our system is as follows:

- CentOS7
- NIS for auth
- home folders on nfs share
- single sudoers file on NFS share for all machines.

so far, item one and two work fine.  but, when I change my `sudo.conf` file to point to the global sudo file

`/fs/global` is a mountpoint for an NFS share

inside the `/etc/sudo.conf` file:

`Plugin sudoers_policy sudoers.so sudoers_file=/fs/global/sudo/common/etc/sudoers`

whenever i try to do `visudo`, i get permission denied (doing it logged into console as root)

I think i have narrowed the problem down to SELinux not being happy.  I know this because if i disable SELinux, it works.  but for this particular group of servers, the apps I'm loading require SELinux.  So, what magic do i have to perform to make this work?

the authconfig i use

```
/sbin/authconfig --enablenis
          --nisdomain="{{ pan_nis_domain }}"
          --nisserver="{{ pan_nis_fqdn }}"
          --passalgo="md5"
          --enablecache
          --update
```

and the ansibles for SELinux i have so far

```
- name: Set ypbind to allow NIS to run
  seboolean:
    name: allow_ypbind
    state: yes
    persistent: yes

- name: Allow home folders mapped across NFS drives
  seboolean:
    name: use_nfs_home_dirs
    state: yes
    persistent: yes
```

edit:

The audit log doesn't show any errors

```
[root@cent1 audit]# tail -5 audit.log
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1553186275.802:2494): pid=26871 uid=0 auid=800 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:79:94:71:c9:57:85:a7:cf:86:7c:ae:f7:29:7c:4c:16:75:33:a5:6f:17:e8:5e:f6:1c:73:75:56:e8:f1:91:17 direction=? spid=26875 suid=800  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1553186296.734:2495): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1553186296.736:2496): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1553186296.765:2497): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1553186296.776:2498): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_xauth acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
[root@cent1 audit]# visudo
visudo: /fs/global/sudo/common/etc/sudoers: Permission denied
[root@cent1 audit]# tail -5 audit.log
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1553186275.802:2494): pid=26871 uid=0 auid=800 ses=5 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:79:94:71:c9:57:85:a7:cf:86:7c:ae:f7:29:7c:4c:16:75:33:a5:6f:17:e8:5e:f6:1c:73:75:56:e8:f1:91:17 direction=? spid=26875 suid=800  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1553186296.734:2495): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1553186296.736:2496): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1553186296.765:2497): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1553186296.776:2498): pid=26893 uid=800 auid=800 ses=5 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_xauth acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=cent1.mycompany.com addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
[root@cent1 audit]#
```

Comment: `/var/log/audit/audit.log` should tell you what is being denied by SELinux.

Comment: commented above

Comment: var/log/secure doesn't mention anything about it either

Comment: You sure this isn't just a typical NFS root_squash?

Comment: `visudo` will want to create a `/fs/global/sudo/common/etc/sudoers.tmp` lock file so it needs to be able to write there

Comment: i don't think its a root_squash issue because i have thousands of other machines that mount to that and work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Hampton, turns out you were right.  I'm new to this network and still learning, turns out the custom version of sudo they use here stripped out all the security features, like access to the sudoers file.  using stock sudo, if fails, using the custom version, it works.  so i configured everything to use our internal custom version.  Thanks